# Stop AVPlayer video when a new UITableViewCell is selected

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, avplayer

I want to show a video accordingly to the selected cell in my tableview. I want to show the video in a view in my vc.

The following code is showing the correct videos when the cells are tapped but whenever i select a new cell the audio from the old video is still there. How can i remove it ?

Setting up the view in my vc:

```
    func setupView(for url: URL) {
        let player = AVPlayer(url: url)
        let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
        playerLayer.frame = self.videoView.bounds
        self.videoView.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
        player.play()
    }
```

didSelectRow code:

```
 let selectedExercise = exercises[indexPath.row]
        setupView(for: URL(string: selectedExercise.videoUrl)!)
```

My guess is that i should pause/stop the previous video before showing the new one. But i don't know how to.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's happend because you create new instance of AVPlayer every tap.

To solve your problem, you need to move
`let player = AVPlayer(url: url)`
outside of `setupView()` and call it only once. You could move it in `init()` for example.

For updating asset (video url) in `setupView()` you could use
`player.replaceCurrentItem(with: AVPlayerItem(url: url))`
.